# Hide port number in URL exposed by NGINX Docker container

Tags: docker, nginx

I run Docker NGINX container with exposed ports `8080` and `8443`.

So I visit welcome NGINX page at:
`http://www.nginx.test:8080`

---

I'm trying to figure out IF it's possible to hide/remove port in URL.

So I visit welcome NGINX page at:
`http://www.nginx.test`

---

Since the NGINX is reverse proxy server it should work. Still new to NGINX and
I had to Google some answers and basically they are applied in tries bellow.

First I tried *(didn't work)* NGINX's directive `proxy_redirect` at *server* level like this:

```
server {
    listen 8080;
    listen [::]:8080;
    server_name www.nginx.test;

    proxy_redirect $scheme://$server_name:8080 $scheme://$server_name;
}
```

Then I tried *(didn't work)* NGINX's directive `proxy_pass` at *location* level like this:

```
server {
    listen 8080;
    listen [::]:8080;
    server_name www.nginx.test;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_pass $scheme://$server_name;
    }
}
```

Probably there's more than that to make it work.

Comment: The default port for `http` and `https` protocols are 80 and 443 respectively. To remove the port number from a URL you must listen on the default port.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`http://www.nginx.test` is interpreted as `http://www.nginx.test:80` (and with SSL `https://www.nginx.test`==`https://www.nginx.test:443`).

So you have to listen on port `80` if you want to drop it from the URL.

With docker, you can map a port of the host to a different port in the container.
So without changing the content of your NGINX container, you can simply map port `80` of your docker server to port `8080` of your nginx container:

```
docker container run ... --publish 80:8080 your_image ...
```

Comment: I had no idea that it's a browser's job to hide these ports. I don't know if it also works with the alternate port `8080` but I am glad that I learned something :)